# Would recyclerview work on an android device with Jellybean?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, backwards-compatibility

TO display a list of items I am using the latest RecyclerView in my app.
I want to know would it only work on devices having android 5.0 or would it on work on lower versions as well ?

Comment: I recommend reading the basics about Android Support Library [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html).

Comment: Pleased you got your answer. In the future, if you need to add commentary about question quality or voting, please add it to the comments - it doesn't belong in posts. Readers just want to see succinct questions and answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's backwards-compatible, assuming you include the support library for [RecyclerView v7](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-recyclerview) in your application's `build.gradle` file:

> Make sure you have downloaded the Android Support Repository using the SDK Manager.
>
> 1. Open the `build.gradle` file for your application.
> 2. Add the support
>      library feature project identifier to the dependencies section just like this:

```
dependencies {
     ...
     compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0.+" 
}
```

That one will work down as low as Android 2.1 (API level 7), hence the name v7

Comment: Is there a non-support version of RecyclerView ?

Comment: Thanks, I already did that. Just wanted to make sure because I am in super hurry and got slightly doubtful when manager asked about it :-)