# Retrofit 2 in a CustomView

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, retrofit2, android-custom-view

In my code I am using an internet example that work fine using Retrofit2 and custom recyclerview but I decide to use this application in android starting at version 4.1.2 so the recyclerview doesn't work there. So, there is a possibility to change the custom recyclerview to a custom listview?

**Lista_productos.java**

```
public class Lista_productos extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
private List<Elementos_fila_productos> elementos;
private RecyclerviewAdapter adapter;
private ApiInterface apiInterface;

static LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

static PopupWindow popupWindow;

static TextView nombre_seleccionado;

static FrameLayout frameLayout;

static String cantidad_deseada;

static char hola;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lista_productos);


    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_tablillas);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);


    if(getIntent().getExtras() != null){

        String type = getIntent().getExtras().getString("type");

        buscarInformacion(type);
    }

}


public void buscarInformacion(String type){

    apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

    Call<List<Elementos_fila_productos>> call = apiInterface.getElementosInfo(type);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Elementos_fila_productos>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Elementos_fila_productos>> call, Response<List<Elementos_fila_productos>> response) {

            elementos = response.body();
            adapter = new RecyclerviewAdapter(elementos, Lista_productos.this);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Elementos_fila_productos>> call, Throwable t) {

            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Lista_productos.this, R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog_Alert);
            builder.setCancelable(true);
            builder.setTitle("Error!");
            builder.setMessage("mensaje");
            builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            });


            final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();




        }
    });

}

}
```

**ListaComprasAdapter.java**

```
public class ListaComprasAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

ArrayList<String> nombre;
ArrayList<String> cantidad;
ArrayList<String> precio;
ArrayList<String> total;

Context mContext;

//constructor
public ListaComprasAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<String> nombre, ArrayList<String> cantidad, ArrayList<String> precio, ArrayList<String> total) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.cantidad = cantidad;
    this.precio = precio;
    this.total = total;
}

public int getCount() {
    return nombre.size();
}

public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View arg1, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_lista_de_compras, viewGroup, false);

    TextView Nombre = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.nombre_del_producto);
    TextView Cantidad = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.cantidad);
    TextView Precio = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.precio);
    TextView Total = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.precio_total_producto);

    Nombre.setText(nombre.get(position));
    Cantidad.setText(cantidad.get(position));
    Precio.setText(precio.get(position));
    Total.setText(total.get(position));


    return row;
}

}
```

**Elementos_fila_productos.java** : the elements of each row

```
public class Elementos_fila_productos {

@SerializedName("ID")
private String ID;

@SerializedName("Caracteristicas")
private String Caracteristicas;

@SerializedName("Precio")
private int Precio;

@SerializedName("Grosor")
private String Grosor;

@SerializedName("Disponibles")
private int Disponible;

@SerializedName("Imagen")
private String Imagen;



public String getGrosor() {
    return Grosor;
}

public String getID() {
    return ID;
}

public String getCaracteristicas() {
    return Caracteristicas;
}

public int getPrecio() {
    return Precio;
}

public int getDisponible() {
    return Disponible;
}

public String getImagen() {
    return Imagen;
}
}
```

**ApiInterface.java**

```
public interface ApiInterface {

@GET("tablillas2.php")


    //revisar en el caso de que no funcione
Call<List<Elementos_fila_productos>> getElementosInfo(@Query("item_type") String item_type);
}
```

**ApiClient.java**

```
public class ApiClient {

public static final String Base_Url = "http://creadorjuancarloscfapptablilla.esy.es/appTablillas/";

public static Retrofit retrofit;


public static Retrofit getApiClient(){

    if (retrofit==null){

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(Base_Url).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
    }

    return retrofit;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like RecyclerView does work for Android 4.1.2. See the accepted answer for this question: [Would recyclerview work on an android device with Jellybean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32348624/would-recyclerview-work-on-an-android-device-with-jellybean)