# There is a horizontal scroll view containing a Linear Layout, the dynamically created Imageview's inside the Linear Layout have problems

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

In a Table Row, there is a horizontal scroll view containing a Linear Layout,
The intention is to place 5 Imageview's inside the Linear Layout dynamically

The problem is it seems the Imageview's are shifted and the Linear Layout does not fill the horizontal scroll view

Here is the xml:

```
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/table_3_Row_7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0.1mm"
        android:background="@color/color21"
        android:gravity="center"
        >

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_span="3"
            android:id="@+id/table_3_Row_7_HSV1"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal"
            android:fadeScrollbars="false"
            android:scrollbarSize="0.5mm"
            android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal="@color/colorDevider"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/table_3_Row_7_HSV1LL"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:background="@color/color02"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                >

            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/table_3_Row_7_ImageView1"
            android:layout_span="3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@color/color21"
            >

        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
```

The mentioned Liniear Layout is **table_3_Row_7_HSV1LL**

And the code is as following:

```
int mMaxCount = 5;
ImageView[]mImageView = new ImageView[mMaxCount];

LinearLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
//params1.setMargins(10, 75, 0, 0);
params1.setMargins(100, 0, 0, 0);
params1.height = 200;
params1.width  = 200;

LinearLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
//params2.setMargins(100, 85+20, 0, 0);
params2.setMargins(100, 0, 0, 0);
params2.height = 170;
params2.width  = 170;

LinearLayout.LayoutParams params3 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
//params3.setMargins(100, 95+20, 0, 0);
params3.setMargins(100, 0, 0, 0);
params3.height = 140;
params3.width  = 140;

LinearLayout.LayoutParams params4 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
//params4.setMargins(100, 105+20, 0, 0);
params4.setMargins(100, 0, 0, 0);
params4.height = 110;
params4.width  = 110;

LinearLayout.LayoutParams params5 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
//params5.setMargins(100, 115+20, 0, 0);
params5.setMargins(100, 0, 0, 0);
params5.height = 80;
params5.width  = 80;
params5.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

mLayoutStruct.getLayout_table_3_Row_7_HSV1LL().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

for (int i = 0; i < mMaxCount; i++)
{
    mImageView[i] = new ImageView(mContext);
    //mImageView[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    mImageView[i].setTag("T"+"I"+i);
    mImageView[i].setId(i);
    mImageView[i].setFocusable(true);
    mImageView[i].setClickable(true);

    if (i == 0)
    {

        //Picasso.with(mContext).load(R.drawable.size1).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher).resize(200, 200).into(mImageView[i]);
        mImageView[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.size1);
        mLayoutStruct.getLayout_table_3_Row_7_HSV1LL().addView(mImageView[i], params1);
    }
    else if (i == 1)
    {
        //Picasso.with(mContext).load(R.drawable.size1).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher).resize(170, 170).into(mImageView[i]);
        mImageView[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.size1);
        mLayoutStruct.getLayout_table_3_Row_7_HSV1LL().addView(mImageView[i], params2);
    }
    else if (i == 2)
    {
        //Picasso.with(mContext).load(R.drawable.size1).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher).resize(140, 140).into(mImageView[i]);
        mImageView[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.size1);
        mLayoutStruct.getLayout_table_3_Row_7_HSV1LL().addView(mImageView[i], params3);
    }
    else if (i == 3)
    {
        //Picasso.with(mContext).load(R.drawable.size1).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher).resize(110, 110).into(mImageView[i]);
        mLayoutStruct.getLayout_table_3_Row_7_HSV1LL().addView(mImageView[i], params4);
    }
    else if (i == 4)
    {
        //Picasso.with(mContext).load(R.drawable.size1).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher).resize(80, 80).into(mImageView[i]);
        mImageView[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.size1);
        mLayoutStruct.getLayout_table_3_Row_7_HSV1LL().addView(mImageView[i], params5);
    }
}
```

The background color of horizontal scroll view is White
The background color of the Linear Layout is Red
I expect the Red color continues till the end of White color and covers it
Another point is when horizontally scrolling, I just see 4 Imageview's instead of 5

[image]

Comment: why not use recycler view ?

Comment: API 22 is start of recycler view, I need less

Answer (score 1):

**First of All:**

1. Its Better to Use [RecylerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView) to Add Items to a list. [this](https://demonuts.com/android-horizontal-recyclerview/) example may help you.
2. RecylerView is [Backward compatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32348624/would-recyclerview-work-on-an-android-device-with-jellybean) so it runs on older version that api 22 you dont need to set minSDK to 22.
3. Your Solution for Adding item to Linearlayout should be better. you can make array of your params to avoid if/else inside loop.

**Answer:**

You See 4 ImageView because You Forget To Add

```
mImageView[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.size1);
```

inside your `else if (i == 3)` So it adds imageview with empty Background that is not visible.

**And**

for covering all the WHITE color of your horizontal scroll view by RED you have to set `android:fillViewport="true"` on the `HorizentalScrollView` like below:

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/table_3_Row_7_HSV1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:layout_span="3"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:fadeScrollbars="false"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:scrollbarSize="0.5mm"
            android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal="@color/gray"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal">
```

Comment: Sorry, Modifying the code in StackOverflow I forgot to add it , when it is added then I still see 4 Imageview's, Apart from that android:fillViewport="true" did not worked

Comment: @AndroidHV try  android:layout_width="match_parent" and android:fillViewport="true" at the same time for your HorizontalScrollView

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by
1 - Deleting `android:layout_gravity="center"` from the LinearLayout
2 - Utilizing setPadding to the horizontal scroll view to shift it down to the center of the table row

Answer (score -1):

For the below point you need to change the code as shown below.

"Another point is when horizontally scrolling, I just see 4 Imageview's instead of 5"

for (int i = 0; i < mMaxCount; i++)

to

for (int i = 0; i <=mMaxCount; i++)